# Contrast enhancement in HSV color

Tags: image-processing

I follow [this paper](http://www.jips-k.org/dlibrary/JIPS_v09_no1_paper9.pdf) for contrast enhancement.
I found in Equation 2 that L is the value (V) level corresponding to the cumulative probability distribution function (CDF) of 0.1 (page 144-145). 
What does it mean and how to get L value?
Then V channel is normalized, is that normalized to maximum 255?
Anybody can explain me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to create a histogram of V :  H

and then find an L that satisfies:

```
sum(H(1:L))/sum(H) = 0.1
```

Comment: That means only one L for one V channel image?

Comment: Yes, looks that way.  L defines z, and "z is the image dependent parameter"